# Disable windows "check for a solution" for a developing application

Tags: visual-studio, crash-reports

I am developing an application with Visual Studio; it can happen this application crashes for any reason
(and this can occur often in early stages).

Today the windows automatic problem reporter had sent to Microsoft the report of many crashes (I think collected for days) of my application, of course not finding any solution.

I am a bit disappointed as I was typing on Visual Studio when the popup of "Send report" came up and was activated when I hit the space-bar, so the report was sent.

It is possible to disable the crash report collecting for Visual Studio developed apps?

I know I can totally disable this facility (for example following [these instructions](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/disable-windows-is-checking-for-a-solution-to-the-problem-prompt-after-a-program-hangs-up.193376/)), but I'd like to leave it on as it solved (very rarely in fact) some driver or common application problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  You can't filter the types of crash reports that are collected.  I'm not sure why you are concerned.  First off, WER (Windows Error Reporting) will not collect crash reports if you are debugging your application in Visual Studio when the crash occurs.  Secondly, the WER crash reporting mechanism relies on a product mapping to actually "bucket" your crash reports.  If you have not "mapped" your application code, and, you most likely haven't since you're still working on it, none of your crash data is stored on the Microsoft systems.  In effect, Microsoft does not save the data for any code that has not been previously mapped.

Comment: I am concerned as it seems stupid to me to send crash report of an application I am working on! Moreover the report said it sent 10MB of data which is a big bunch and I want to avoid useless network activity

Comment: Was this a release version you were running at the time?  If so, you cannot stop the collection on an individual basis.  Otherwise, if you were running debug, crash reports are not collected.

Comment: After years I am still concerned with this issue, as the error reporting keeps buggin me out on a random basis...